# Cplex OPL model with Java data file

Tags: java, cplex, opl

I'm a new user of cplex.
I want to use a java code to generate a data file to use it in a cplex opl model.
what command should I insert in my opl code and my java one so I can do such thnig.
Thak you.

Answer (score 0):

- in java you could use IloOplModel.printExternalData(java.io.OutputStream outs)

  - in OPL you    could use {st  ring} printExternalData(title) in IloOplModel

You have some OPL+java examples in CPLEX_Studio1263\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java

regards